# Reset PostgreSQL primary key to 1

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, reset

Is there a way to reset the primary key of a PostgreSQL table to start at 1 again on a populated table?

Right now it's generating numbers from 1000000 and up. I want it all to reset and start to 1, keeping all my existing data intact.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

See a better option here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272164/5190

Primary keys that autoincrement (i.e., columns with data type `serial primary key`) are associated with a [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive//functions-sequence.html). You can set the next value for any sequence using the `setval(<seqname>, <next_value>)` function. Note that to actually execute the function by itself you need to use [`SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20040630135450.GB13891%40wolff.to), like this: `SELECT setval(<seqname>, <next_value>)`

The name of the auto created sequences when using serial are `<table>_<column>_seq`

Comment: You need to put "SELECT" in front of the call, e.g., `SELECT setval('table_id_seq', 10000)`

Comment: If I do `SELECT setval('table_id_seq', 1)`, when I insert a new record the id takes value 2, instead of 1. [Paweł Gościcki's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5272164/505893) works. (PostgreSQL 9.3)

Comment: @bluish Presumably what happened is the sequence number is incremented before new primary key is assigned, ie. you'd need to reset it to 0. But I agree the other solution is better anyway.

Answer (score 257):

The best way to reset a sequence to start back with number 1 is to execute the following:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <tablename>_<id>_seq RESTART WITH 1
```

So, for example for the `users` table it would be:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 1
```

Comment: The `WITH 1` parameter is redundand and it can be ommited

Comment: That's the only right answer as it really reset the sequence.

Comment: The **big problem** on indexes generated automatically by CREATE TABLE clause, is that we not know  the name (and the suffix is not `seq`, can by `pk` etc.)... But it is easy by  on psql by `\d my_table_name`. Or check by SQL, `SELECT  * FROM pg_indexes WHERE  tablename like '%my_table_name%'`

Comment: Just beat my head on this problem. If the table has data in it and you want it to start where it left off, you still want to pass `WITH 1` or leave it out. If you specify `WITH 123` or whatever the current highest value, it's going to ADD that value to your next row. Probably not what you want.

Comment: I needed to prefix the sequence-identifier with the schema-name, otherwise i got "relation 'tablename_id_seq' does not exist". This naming convention can be looked up by "\d <tablename>" and the default-value (nextval...) for the id column. So essentially in my case `ALTER SEQUENCE auth.roles_id_seq RESTART WITH 5;`

Answer (score 18):

`TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY;`

### This will delete all of your data.

Maybe some users looking for something like this as I am.

Comment: The fact that you have just copy-pasted this command ***without warning users that it will delete ALL ROWS in the table*** makes this a Very Bad "answer". Quite frankly, it should be deleted. I would down-vote it more if I could.

Answer (score 5):

@bluish actually inserting a new record using an auto-incremented primary key, is just like using a sequence explicitly this way:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, col1, ...) VALUES (MySeq.nextval(), val1, ...)
```

So, if you want the first id to be 1, you should have to set your sequence to 0. But it's out of bounds, so you must use the ALTER SEQUECE statement.
So, if you have a serial field named number in your table menu, for exemple:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE menu_number_seq RESTART
```

will make the job perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, empty the table then reset the primary key.

let suppose table **population** you have.

`delete from population`

`ALTER SEQUENCE population_id_seq" RESTART WITH 1`

Answer (score -1):

@ZootHii
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31778600)

Comment: Same as I posted for ZootHii: The fact that you have just copy-pasted this command ***without warning users that it will delete ALL ROWS in the table*** makes this a Very Bad "answer". But this one is worse, because ***this one will CASCADE the data deletion to other tables that depend on it*** (e.g. by means of foreign keys). Again, this is another "answer" that should be deleted. I would down-vote it more if I could.

Comment: First thing, if try to truncate a table that has relation will not allow to truncate.