# Postgres Duplicate Key Error Code

Tags: sql, postgresql

currently I'm using postgresql as my database and I import all the data into the table through MS Excel csv format. All things went out smoothly but the problem is whenever I want to insert additional data into the table for example using the following code:

```
insert into country (name)
values ('America');
```

it keeps pop up an error of

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "effect_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (country_id)=(1) already exists.
********** Error **********

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "effect_pkey"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (country_id)=(1) already exists.
```

when I keep trying to insert the data, the error getting is similar just the country_id in the error message is increasing. then I can only insert the data when I surpass the existing ID in my table. I would like to know how can I solve this out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add the table definition for the country table to your question. (country_id is a serial?)

Comment: @joop ya the id is in serial format and it's just a simple table with ID and NAME,

Comment: Than probably your data import forgot to reset the serial (to the maximal occuring value in the table)

Comment: @joop how should I overcome this issue..hmmmm

Comment: You have to reset your primary serial key to the current value+1 imported from your file: You can chieve this like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819323/1216680

Comment: And yes: this is probably a duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT setval('country_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(country_id) FROM country) );
```

(I don't know the *exact* names, since the OP did not give a table definition in his question)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution now might be to use `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` to allow PostgreSQL to assign the id while ensuring it's not ever assigned externally.

See for example https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-identity-column/