# Postgres truncate restart identity doesn't restart identity

Tags: postgresql

Pretty much as the topic says.

```
truncate table "Account" restart identity cascade;
insert into "Account" ("name", "enabled") values ("test", 1);
select * from "Account";
```

Outputs:

```
 accountId | name | enabled
-----------+------+---------
        14 | test |       1
(1 row)
```

This is the schema for the table:

```
                                       Table "public.Account"
  Column   |          Type          |                           Modifiers
-----------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 accountId | integer                | not null default nextval('"Account_accountId_seq"'::regclass)
 name      | character varying(255) | not null
 enabled   | integer                | not null
Indexes:
    "Account_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("accountId")
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""AccountPropertyAccess"" CONSTRAINT "AccountPropertyAccess_accountId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("accountId") REFERENCES "Account"("accountId")
    TABLE ""User"" CONSTRAINT "User_accountId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("accountId") REFERENCES "Account"("accountId")
```

And here are some extra words because stack exchange thinks I don't have enough words because I have too much code.

Comment: Show the table schema `\d "Account"`

Comment: Your insert statement in the first code block is invalid. String literals have to use single quotes `"test"` denotes a column, not a value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you did not create the column as  `serial` column and thus Postgres does not know that the sequence "belongs" to the column and therefore "restart identity" doesn't reset the sequence.

You can fix that by either re-creating the table using `serial` instead of `integer` and a default value.

Or you can just tell Postgres that the column "owns" the sequence:

```
alter sequence "Account_accountId_seq" owned by "Account"."accountId";
```

---

<sup>Btw: using quoted identifiers is usually much more trouble than it's worth (at leas in my experience). Most of the time it's better to never use quoted identifiers at all,  e.g. `create table Account (...)` instead of `create table "Account" (...)`</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have an auto increment sequence id. You will need to reset it too.

The PostgreSQL documentation [shows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altersequence.html)

```
ALTER SEQUENCE Account RESTART WITH 1;
```

There are a few questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342440/reset-auto-increment-counter-in-postgres) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819292/reset-postgresql-primary-key-to-1) regarding it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found easier way

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Account RESTART IDENTITY;
```