# PostgreSQL Restart Serial Primary Key

Tags: postgresql

I have a table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testing.table_comparison_summaries
(
  ID SERIAL
, reference_database_name varchar(255)
, reference_schema_name varchar(255)
, reference_table_name varchar(255)
, reference_deleted_row_count INT
, compare_database_name varchar(255)
, compare_schema_name varchar(255)
, compare_table_name varchar(255)
, compare_changed_row_count INT
, compare_new_row_count INT
, comparison_timestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
, CONSTRAINT pk_table_comparison_summaries PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
;
```

I want to restart the ID value as it's a table I'm doing a trunc/reload on.

I saw this thread:  [Reset PostgreSQL primary key to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819292/reset-postgresql-primary-key-to-1/5272164#5272164) , but it is not working for me.

The command I am using is this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE
table_comparison_summaries id seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using `truncate` then you can use `truncate table ... restart identity`

Comment: what exactly does "not working" mean? What is the error you get?

Comment: I figured it out, I wasn't actually using the name of the sequence. Problem solved, but thanks though, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some useful documentation: https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-alter-sequence-in-postgresql

The correct code to run was

```
ALTER SEQUENCE
testing.table_comparison_summaries_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

In PGAdmin, off to the left, you can see a list of sequences for that schema. Use that.